What do you call people who believe in purpose in life and afterlife reincarnation, but don't believe in God?
In the formal interpretation, they seem to draw a distinct line, claiming that atheists believe that death is the cessation of the existence of the individual.
But that contradicts the world's literature created by atheists where multidimensional and multi-world scenarios are common and beloved.

Did you delete your comment question What would correspond in Hinduism to matrix-simulation? In any case... I'd say karma is a good starting point to grok being under conditions/affliction larger than we can grasp

This is quite close to mainstream Hinduism. To wit:
The religious leader Chandrashekhar Saraswati was once asked who or what defines Hindu. This is invariably a contentious question because Hinduism is very disorganized with nothing like a central Pope, universal deity etc.
OTOH he comes as close as one can get to a Pope in Hinduism in the sense that he was highly revered and referred to as paramacharya — our revered pontiff.
His answer as I remember it:
In order to be a Hindu

one needs to believe in the soul
in the afterlife
in karma

Beyond that you are free to pick whatever God/gods/guru(s) you like — this is a central concept in Hinduism called ishta devata — my chosen format of deity.

So some (the majority) choose the personalized mythologized figures — Ram, Krishna, Shiva etc
The more philosophically oriented choose the impersonal Brahman.
[Brahma, male is in the mythology with Shiva, Vishnu etc. Brahman is neuter and is not a person but more like an abstract principle of Being-Awareness-Bliss]
some choose a more empirically indisputable entity like the Sun, the earth, the Ganges river etc
some choose their parents. See Shravan Kumar
some choose the planets who are effective mediators between the empirical and the theological levels. vide the passage from the astrological text the Parashara samhita: (in weekday order)

the sun is the essence of the soul of the universe
the moon is the essence of Mind
Mars is the essence of strength
Mercury is the essence of communication and worldly wisdom
Jupiter is the essence of spiritual wisdom
Venus is the essence of love
Saturn is the essence of misery and suffering


some choose an abstract empirical principle like seva service to their fellows
some choose their guru.
vide Ramana Maharshi: Father, Son, Holy spirit of Christianity corresponds to God, Guru, Atma of Hinduism

So in short to be a Hindu you can worship whoever you like however you like or nobody in particular.

I feel a bit weird about like, "oh, simulationism is a kind of hinduism". It feels like it risks leaning into all the worst aspects of new-age-y "taohindubuddism as an exploitable aesthetic removed from any context", and in some sense it feels more accurate to say "the movie The Matrix was inspired by various religions, including hinduism"?

In particular, "So in short to be a Hindu you can worship whoever you like however you like or nobody in particular" seems out of step with e.g. contemporary reality around Hindutva, anti-Muslim, anti-Sikh, etc. sentiment in India. Which is not to say Hinduism is inherently bad or reactionary or anything. Just that it, like all religions, is not defined by a minimal set of beliefs, but is interrelated with the cultural, political, social etc.

@kaia see Hindutva

@Kaia exploitable aesthetic removed from any context strong agreement on this. Eg. I find it ludicrous & absurd when westerners call themselves Buddhist and say they don't believe in karma. Even worse justify it by saying Buddha agrees. Sure Buddha said some things in that vein but if you take it with the entire civilizational matrix in which it was uttered it is nonsense to dispute karma as a universal axiom of Indic religions. [Inter alia even Jesus taught karma — As you sow you shall reap — but that civilization did not reify it. Or The Nicene council erased it... dunno]

@Kaia "new-age-y"...
"taohindubuddism as an exploitable aesthetic removed from any context"
etc.
Yes I can see that this answer as it currently stands can be criticised that way.
I will see how I can amend/add to rectify that.
As far as comment (length) is concerned: How about I say:
Christianity vs Hinduism is
logos-orientation vs mythos-orientation
Also as part of a larger dichotomy list. Does that make a clearer point??

I mean, I'm always going to be skeptical of large dichotomy list; it takes a lot for me to accept "here is the overarching pattern; these things are are in association and oriented across from these other things that are in association with themselves," because I'm a stubborn pattern-hater :P (E.g., while Christian doctrine absolutely rejects reincarnation, ask a Christian and more likely than not they'll say they absolutely believe in it. People are contradictory and complicated!) But it's your answer to edit, not mine.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
